# Does clicking on multiple buttons in a web page abort already long running ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

We have a web page with multiple buttons. We are using javascript/jquery to perform ajax calls. On clicking on 'Show Data' button, ajax call fetch the data and data will be bind to grid. Records count can be more than 10k. Therefore we are retrieving only first 100 records on 'Show Data' button click and binding the first 100 records to grid. Below the grid we have previous and next buttons. On clicking of next buttons we are retrieving next 100 records using the ajax call and binding to grid.

In the grid we have various currency columns. At the top of the grid we have some currency calculation section. So on clicking of 'Show Data' button, we want to compute that currency calculations using ajax calls on whole set of records count(e.g. on 10k records and not on 100 records. In grid at first time we are displaying on 100 records not 10k).

Clicking on 'Show Data' button, grid will be displayed immediately but doing that currency calculation at the same time taking some more time. We are doing currency calculations in loop(batch of 100 records at a time). So suppose currency calculations is happening in background and at the same time user clicks of next button then what will happen with ongoing ajax calls of currency calculations? will they work smoothly or will they get aborted or will we facing any issues with either ajax calls of currency calculations or ajax calls of next button?

Please note that we are using async:true for all ajax operations.

Comment: No, clicking on multiple links will send multiple requests. once the request is sent it is processed by the server.

Comment: Only way it would abort it is if it navigates the page away.

Comment: So one way to prevent it is to disable the next button until you are done processing and than re-enable it.

Comment: @epascarello It won't abort upon navigating away from the page unless you navigate away before the ajax is sent. (maybe what you meant?) Once it is sent it is sent there is no way to stop it client side.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks for comments. We have requirement that next button should not be disabled and at the same time calculations should go on.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn If an http request is open, the browser and kill off the open connections before the navigation event will happen. That is what I was referring too. If the button does not navigate away, than nothing happens.

Comment: @ShaileshJaiswal So are you seeing any problems? It should be fine, just remember that if user clicks the button multiple times there is no way to guarantee that click 2's Ajax call will come after Click 1's.

Comment: @epascarello As soon as user clicks on 'Show Data' or Next button, we hide/disable those buttons and show/enable only after the data is loaded.

Comment: Which is what I suggested above, but you said you could not do it.. I am lost. lol

Comment: @epascarello I mean to say during the display of grid it should not be disabled and calculations should go on in background. When the user clicks on next button then it should be disabled until and unless next 100 records is bind to grid. Then it should be enabled

Comment: @AjayGupta Are you sure about that comment you made? [XMLHttpRequest.abort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort)

Comment: @gforce301 Thanks for pointing that out! I didn't knew about it.